# Converting xlsx to xls using Microsoft Office Compitablity Pack's excelcnv

Tags: excel, ms-office, command-line-tool

The internet says that you can convert xlsx files to xls files using Microsoft Office Compitablity like this:
`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\excelcnv" -nme -oice D:\test\new.xlsx D:\test\old.xls`
However, this works backwards - it converts xls files to xlsx files. Does anyone know the `excelcnv` switches to convert xlsx to xls?

Comment: [citation needed]. The [first source I found](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/innovateonoffice/thread/daa3b45c-5c4b-44c1-bb35-a108b8dc13f8) via a quick search that deals with this notes that this isn't possible using `excelcnv`.

Comment: Is there another free command line tool that can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, using the compatibility (conversion) pack for Office 2003, simply switching the places of the parameters in the example you cite works; e.g. if this also works for ~\Office14 (which I assume and hope it does), change the command this way:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\excelcnv" -nme -oice D:\test\old.xls D:\test\new.xlsx
```

In my case, the particular command that gets it to work, which I found [yonder](http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2014/08/free-convert-for-excel-files-xls-to-xlsx.html) (and simply reversed the parameters like so), is this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\excelcnv.exe" -oice "C:\scripts\test1.xls" "C:\scripts\test1.xlsx"
```

Comment: Well, I'm no longer working with Office, and nowadays I try to stay as far away from Windows as possible - so I can't verify the answer. I'll simply accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question whilst looking for a way to convert XLSX to XLS using the command line.  I couldn't get the solution presented here to work, but I managed to find a solution by installing Libre Office 5 then using the command:

```
"C:\Program Files\libreoffice 5\program\soffice.exe" --convert-to xls "original-file.xlsx"
```

This outputted the file as "original-file.xls"