# C# Convert Excel.Workbook object to XML file

Tags: c#, xml, excel, xls

I'm trying to change old GUI C# app. Program is XML file converter in output I have XLS file.
I have task to create new file format instead of XLS, it should be XML.

Algorithm is complicated and I don't won't to write it from beginning.

In Excel we can simple 'Save as' XML and it works, but I'm unavailable to do this in C#.

File format is `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = null;`

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1e33e36.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707247/converting-xlsx-to-xls-using-microsoft-office-compitablity-packs-excelcnv